# Rainbow Tables - Hash Reduction - Java

Tags: java, hash, rainbowtable

Can you give me some advice on a good reduction function for rainbow table hashes to implement in java?
The reduction functions I saw in C++ mostly used unsigned 64bit integer what Java isn't capable of natively now and I'd like to find another solution. (Should be available at Java 8.)

Alternatively: If someone knows a library in Java that supports the - at least not inefficient - usage (and maybe cration) of rainbow tables, please tell me. Would be great not to implement that on my own.

Sadly I'm bound to Java as a platform so I can not use the good C++ implementations on the market.

Comment: why do you care about signed or not, java has '>>>' operator, so the sign doesn't matter. In C right bit-shift '>>' is undefined for signed integers but it's well defined in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the algorithm you used consists of additions, subtractions, multiplications and bitwise operations, it is an easy matter to translate it to work with Java `long` instead of unsigned.

Comment: Thank you, I also found this what might be useful for others: [Unsigned in Java](http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html)